# React Native OneSignal: For version 4.5.0, do we still need OneSignal Gradle Plugin?

Tags: react-native, build.gradle, onesignal, gradle-plugin, react-native-onesignal

I'm using OneSignal in my React Native project. I'm upgrading the packages, and I found the following code in `android/app/build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/' } // Gradle Plugin Portal 
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:[0.12.1, 0.99.99]'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'
```

I don't see any reference to the OneSignal Gradle Plugin in the [React Native SDK setup](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/react-native-sdk-setup#section-adding-the-gradle-plugin) docs. I'm using version 4.5.0. Are these lines of code still necessary, or can I remove them?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is necessary.
Since auto linking with newer versions RN should work they didn't include this in the documentation, but still present in the troubleshooting docs.

https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/troubleshooting-react-native